# How to make QtLinguist with Qt5.11 and VS2015 work?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2015

When I first run this option in first picture, I get the error in second picture.
[image]

[image]

However, if I create a new project with current project's files, this option is working well. I don't know why this happens. Can anyone help me solve this? Thank you so much.

I have search much solutions, but neither did them work for my situation.

[The application exited with an error (ExitCode 1)](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTVSADDINBUG-493)

[Qt creating new translation (ts) using Visual gives error - (ExitCode 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719427/qt-creating-new-translation-ts-using-visual-gives-error-exitcode-1)

[How to make QtLinguist shipped with Qt 5.9.1 work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852340/how-to-make-qtlinguist-shipped-with-qt-5-9-1-work)

Comment: The solution contains several different projects, and it's impossible to transfer to a new simple project.

Answer (score 0):

I have fix this problem. Our project list contains one item that its related local file is deleted by others, and I just remove this item. Now everything just be fine. The .tf file is now can produced by Qt tool.